# CSS problem with tag @media, adaptation position of the button

Tags: css

On the page https://sport-print.online/sample-page/ I have a little button "Сравнить". I'm trying to adapt it using the CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px), only screen and (max-device- 
width: 1920px) {
  .compare 
  {

 right: -500px;
 top: -720px;
 width: 70px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding: 0 10px !important;
 padding-right: 20px !important;
 padding-bottom: 10px !important;
 }

 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (max-device- 
width: 1024px) {
.compare 
{

 right: -300px;
 top: -320px;
 width: 70px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding: 0 10px !important;
 padding-right: 20px !important;
 padding-bottom: 10px !important;
 }

 }
```

Only the first part of the code works for width in 1920px. The second part of the code does not work. When the resolution is changed, the button position is not switched. Prompt please in what my error? Please correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the top and right properties do not affect position: static;

It was necessary to specify position: absolute; or position: relative; in the @media properties. Operating code:

```
.compare 
{

 width: 70px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 20px;
 padding: 0 10px !important;
 padding-right: 20px !important;
 padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px), only screen and (max-device-width: 
1920px) {

.compare 
{
 position: absolute;          /* или  position: relative;*/
 right: -500px;
 top: -720px;

}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (max-device-width: 
1024px) {
.compare 
 {

 position: absolute;             /* или  position: relative;*/
 right: -300px;
 top: 700px;

 }

 }
```